# Array of observable element in RxSwift

Tags: ios, iphone, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and working on some sample to test. I have show some data on uitableview with the help of RxSwift. However when I try to delete any item from tableview and reload. Observable array didn't update and due to this scrolling at last item crashes. Below is the code, please help me know what I am doing wrong.

```
self.itemArray = NSMutableArray(objects: "First Item","Second Item","Third Item","Fourth Item","Fifth Item","Sixth Item","Seventh Item","Eight Item","Nineth Item","Tenth Item","Eleventh Item","Twelveth Item","Thirtheenth Item","Fourtheenth Item","Fifteenth Item","Sixteenth Item","Seventhenth Item","First Item","Second Item","Third Item","Fourth Item","Fifth Item","Sixth Item","Seventh Item","Eight Item","Nineth Item","Tenth Item","Eleventh Item","Twelveth Item","Thirtheenth Item","Fourtheenth Item","Fifteenth Item","Sixteenth Item","Seventhenth Item")


var seqValue = Observable.just(self.itemArray)
seqValue
    .bind(to: rxtableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, seqValue) in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.itemArray.object(at: row) as? String
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cell
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)


self.rxtableView.rx.itemDeleted
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self]indexPath in
        self.itemArray.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
        seqValue = Observable.just(self.itemArray)
        self.rxtableView.reloadData()
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it BehaviorSubject, i.e. -

```swift
var seqValue = BehaviorSuject.create(self.itemArray)
```

and instead of 'seqValue = Observable.just(self.itemArray)' do

```swift
seqValue.onNext(self.itemArray)
```

calling '.reloadData()' is not necessary

Comment: I changed to this line let itemValue = BehaviorSubject.init(value: self.itemArray) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is RxSwift's `Variable`:

```
let seqValue = Variable<String>(["First Item", ...])
```

so you in your `.itemDeleted` you can modify that variable:

```
seqValue.value.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

`Variable` is an `Observable`, so changes are propagated automatically. No need to call `reloadData()`.